# Has any Starfleet Captain ever been Court Martialed for violating the Prime Directive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The [Prime Directive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prime_Directive) seems to be a core principle of Starfleet and a bedrock philosophy for their interaction with less developed civilizations, yet seems to be violated with remarkable regularity. Has any Captain actually been court-martialed and/or punished for violation?

Comment: Out of canon, the Star Trek novel "Prime Directive" deals solely with Kirk's court martial and subsequent expulsion from Starfleet for violating the Directive and killing an entire world.

Comment: That seems a rather generous punishment for mass-genocide...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In-canon the answer is no. Captains usually tread a very fine line of morality before deciding to pull the trigger on violating the Prime Directive.

The closest a serving captain seems to have come is in "[Star Trek Into Darkness](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1408101/)" where Captain James T. Kirk and First Officer Spock save a planet's inhabitants from an extinction-inducing volcanic eruption but violate the Prime Directive by exposing the Enterprise to the natives. On returning to Earth, Kirk is threatened with a Court martial and loses command of the Enterprise with Kirk demoted to first officer and the rank of Commander.

Comment: Is "Into Darkness" really considered cannon?

Comment: @hikaruichijyo - sadly yes.

Comment: @ Hikaru & Richard: I can't help thinking aside from Spock being in it nothing connects to any other Trek... Unlike what makes Star Wars I-III cannon, despite some fans try to ignore it's existence, clearly the Clone Wars had happened the NEW TREK can be totally disregarded and it wouldn't mean anything to the rest of Trek.  So do we really need to canonize it?  I'm not trying to argue just pointing out that it might not have to be cannon.

Comment: @Richard I'll accept your first two sentences as a valid correct answer that no Starfleet Captain has ever been court martialed and punished for violating the Prime Directive, and try to forgive the rest.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I think it's best not to get too anxious about things like 'canon'. In the end it's all fiction, so there's very little point in getting worked up over which fictions are more real/less fictional than other fictions.

Comment: There's no official canon guidelines (unlike Star Wars), but Memory-Alpha's standard for canonicity is "the movies and the TV shows". If you're going to start throwing out specific movies or shows, our agreed standards all dissolve and you can throw out any bits you want, like Neelix's haircut.

Comment: I can't help but point out that unless New Canon has somehow introduced the Prime Directive far, far earlier than it was in the Old Canon, that the Prime Directive **did not actually exist** until much later in the timeline, as far forward as Kirk's encounter in "A Piece of the Action".

Comment: @plutor - Yes. I'll often quote from the various sourcebooks but always with the proviso that they don't contradict what we saw on the tv

Comment: Hikaru - in theory it is its own alternate universe, (which - oddly enough! - clashes with typical Trek cause/effect of what actually happens when someone time travels) so to that extent it 'gets to' play fast and loose with the rules. While I can't offer a real objection to JJ-verse as strict non-canon, the line has been 'officially' drawn in regard to works beyond TV and movies. The books are not canon, and even the current people in charge of the JJ-verse can't decide whether "Countdown" (the comic predicting ST XI) is real canon or not. The old stuff is safely compartmentalized.

Comment: In first sentence, replace no with yes. *Star Trek Into Darkness* is also canon you know.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Except that he's only **threatened** with it. That's the closest anyone gets and in reality he only suffers a demotion to the role that he was in a few months ago.

Comment: @Zibbobz That planet's culture had already been irrevocably altered by something 100 years prior, so I don't think it applied (or at least, not as strongly).  Besides, I'd argue instead that it was a part of the Federation from the beginning, coming in by way of the Vulcans who already had a policy not to contact pre-warp civilizations

Comment: @Zibbobz Actually, checking [Memory Alpha's page on the Prime Directive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prime_Directive), it indicates that episode as a reference for it having been made official around 2168, around 100 years before TOS / around 90 years before _Into Darkness_

Comment: @Izkata Did you just take some time out of your day to correct all my bold assertions?  ;)  If so, nicely done.

Comment: @Zibbobz Nah, just coincidence.  I got home from work and posted like 5 or 6 comments all at once

Comment: @ evilsoup & Plutor: I'm not 'worked up' but it was my understanding that Roddenberry had made cannon rules.  Something like, if it was broadcast on television it was cannon except for commercials and all but one episode of the animated series...

Comment: @Stick - I hadn't actually thought of it but time-travel has always been the 'cause/effect' type, as you say. My thought being the Enterprise-C incident from Season 3 (Yesterday's Enterprise).

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza - Roddenberry doesn't rule on canon for Trek. As with most series, the true arbiter is the studio.

Comment: @Richard: While you're not wrong it seems Roddenberry didn't agree: [Trek Canon](http://www.canonwars.com/STCanon.html#III-A)

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza: Roddenberry canon is very strict. It's all stuff that Gene Roddenberry said is canon. He never made blanket statement about "all broadcast on television". He only said that all stuff he "approved for broadcast" is canon. If you were to follow Roddenberry canon then fine - TNG is not canon - Picard is essentially a fanfic.

Comment: @slebetman - I do not understand your reply to 22ndCenturyFza.  Was not it Gene Roddenberry who created Captain Picard & The Next Generation!?  Do you mean Captain Sisko was essentially a fan-fiction as Deep Space 9 was not the Star Trek Mr Roddenberry envisioned?

Answer (score 7):

The only guaranteed way to avoid violating the Prime Directive is to ban space exploration and diplomacy altogether. However, the Prime Directive has done a remarkable job of helping the Federation avoid the type of imperialistic tendencies that human societies have demonstrated throughout our history — especially when contrasted against other galactic powers like the Klingons, Cardassians, Romulans, etc.

Generally, when the Prime Directive is violated (often by subordinates rather than a Starfleet captain), the violations straddle the more morally thorny areas of the Prime Directive: i.e. is it really ethical to allow millions of innocent people to die in favor of allowing "history" to run its natural course? — an argument that suffers from the naturalistic fallacy as well as ignoring the possibility that Starfleet itself is part of the natural system rather than just a neutral observer.

Also, often captains will bend the Prime Directive based on technicalities rather than violating the directive outright, making it easier to justify their actions to Starfleet. (E.g. having the endangered society ask the Starfleet crew for help.)

Another common situation is to prevent or negate the interference by another warp-capable species on a less developed society. There are strong parallels here with Cold War politics, but generally Starfleet captains seem to act on a genuine desire to uphold the underlying principles of the Prime Directive, if not the actual letter of the law. It's akin to a pacifist who believes in non-aggression rather than pure non-violence.

All of this is to say, the Prime Directive is a complex issue with lots of moral and legal grey areas and room for interpretation. And when you take into account Starfleet higher ups like Admiral Ross, who directly aided Section 31 in violating the Prime Directive, it becomes less and less likely that Starfleet captains will be court-martialled every time they save a planet from natural disaster or get seen by a pre-warp civilization or free a shape-shifting space creature from alien captivity.

Of course, they still get reprimanded, no doubt, but the real court-martiallable offenses are situations like *The Omega Glory* or *ST: Insurrection*. In the former case, it's almost certain that Captain Tracey was court-martialled as soon as he was brought back to Starfleet. In the latter case, the vice admiral was killed before he could face justice. Starfleet officials who commit less serious offenses would likely only face a board of inquiry, as Captain Janeway alluded to when confronted with her own violation of the Prime Directive in *Counterpoint*:

> Well, let's just say I usually go with my instincts and sort it out
>   later at the board of inquiry.

Comment: When did Admiral Ross’s actions push up against the Prime Directive?

Comment: @bdesham: In [_Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges_](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Inter_Arma_Enim_Silent_Leges_%28episode%29), Ross assists Sloan in putting a Federation mole on the Romulan Continuing Committee--which is a major violation of the Prime Directive's rule against interfering with the internal affairs of other societies.

Comment: I had actually thought that the Prime Directive only applied to pre-warp societies, but [reading about it on Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prime_Directive) I realize that you’re right: Section 31’s interference in Romulan affairs was forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in understanding the question, the 'Prime Directive' is just that.  It's not a law, rule, etc.  A directive is guidance on how to navigate an issue.  That it's qualified as being prime means that other directives exist and that this one is of greater importance.

So any action against an individual would be for 'not upholding the spirit of starfleet', 'bringing into disrepute', etc.  Not directly for 'dis-obeying the prime directive'.

Answer (score 0):

We know of some captains being on trial: Kirk because of Lt. Finney’s death (who faked it), Picard on the loss of the Stargazer. Both have been cleared of all charges (so no punishment). Michael Edington (not a captain - so probably not answering your question) was tried and found guilty.

Out of universe: if a captain would be found guilty he most certainly would loose his command and we wouldn't see him starring in the series anymore. So if a captain stands trial we can expect that they violated the Prime Directive (giving the circumstances) in a proportional, reasonable way.

Comment: While interesting I think is a little broad as it focuses on court Martians in general rather than the PD

Comment: @Liath: True. The idea of my answer was to say: "No". But I wanted to add a little substance to that ;-)

Comment: So. Many. Spelling. Mistakes!  Aargh!

Comment: @Richard: Sorry about that |-/ Not my native language...

Comment: @Richard: as my copy editor badge demonstrates, that’s what the edit button is for.

Comment: @pauldwaite - and usually I'd be happy to,  except that I'm on my phone

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Thanks for spellchecking it! Looks way better now...

Comment: @Richard - it's pretty poor taste to criticize a non-native speaker for spelling.

Comment: @dvk - but how will he learn?

Comment: @Richard - there's a world of difference between "I noticed this has some spelling mistakes, Fixed them for you." and "So. Many. Spelling. Mistakes! Aargh!".

Comment: There was a TOS book called "The Prime Directive" in which Kirk did lose command of the Enterprise, but once the real reason as to why things happened as they did came out, he was acquitted and resumed command